# yaml.safe_load removes whitespaces if also contains a line break

Tags: python, yaml

I'm working with the library `PyYAML==6.0.1` and trying to retrieve an object from a string representation of a YAML.

The problem is, when I use `yaml.safe_load` with a text containing a line break then it removes the whitespaces.

For example:

```
data = yaml.safe_load("first\n\n         second")
```

returns a string with the linebreak but the whitespaces removed

```
'first\nsecond'
```

If I don't add the line break then the whitespaces are kept.

How can I keep both things (the linebreak and the whitespace)?

Comment: There is no question in your post. In the spirit of this forum, what is your question? Did you check the YAML spec? I think that is valid. Consecutive whitespace in a string elements are replaced with a newline. See https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/ section 6.4 . If you want to preserve line spaces, see section 2.3 . Also section 7.3.3 has the behavior you are seeing `Empty lines, if any, are consumed as part of the line folding.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @KamilCuk I finally checked the official [YAML documentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2) and found a solution for my problem.

My solution was to add a literal scalar into my YAML representation string, and remove the second '\n' because it was not longer needed (see [literal style docs)](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#literal-style):

```
yaml.safe_load("|-\n first\n         second")
```

This way the result of the previous operation is:

```
'first\n         second'
```